# How to assign value to var conditionally

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking for a way to do a conditional assignment of value to a key in an object. In my case i have an old data structure in my json file which is different then the new one so for example now the field is seller1FirstName and before it was seller1FName. What i need is a way to assign the value of this field to a var in my code. I know i could check if one exist and then assign it or if not use the other like this

```
if (data.seller1FirstName) {
   let mySellerFirstName = data.seller1FirstName
 } else {
   let mySellerFirstName = data.seller1FName
 }
```

i am hoping there is a cleaner and shorter way to do this

Comment: `const mySellerFirstName = data.seller1FirstName ?? data.seller1FName;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a ternary 'if' operator to do the same thing in only one line:

```
let mySellerFirstName = data.seller1FirstName ? data.seller1FirstName : data.seller1FName;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the optional chaining operator in addition to the nullish coalescing operator.

```js
let data = {
  seller1FName : 'value'
}

let newValue = data?.seller1FirstName ?? data.seller1FName;

console.log(newValue);
```

Comment: This is not strictly the same. `??` will use the second value if the first is `undefined` or `null`. The `if` check in the original would use the second value if the first is falsey (`undefined`, `null`, or `""`).